# Cannot find Main method using reflection with .NET 5 top level calls

Tags: .net, c#-9.0

```
var pt = Type.GetType("<Program>$");
var m = pt.GetMethod("<Main>$", BindingFlags.Static);
// m is null
```

Okay, I grab the `Program` class, this works fine. But when I go to grab the `Main` method, system cannot find it, and it's not in `pt.GetMembers()` either. What's going on?

Comment: Currently you haven't specified `BindingFlags.Public` or `BindingFlags.NonPublic`. Likewise `GetMembers()` will only return you public members unless you specify that you want non-public ones too... have you tried specifying that?

Comment: I made a similar question yesterday and the answers there are good so I want to link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65164165/how-do-i-get-the-reflection-typeinfo-of-a-c-sharp-9-program-that-use-top-level-s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to specify that you want to see non-public members:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;

var pt = Type.GetType("<Program>$");
var m = pt.GetMethod("<Main>$", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
Console.WriteLine(m); // Prints Void <Main>$(System.String[])
```

Likewise using `GetMembers`, you need to specify you want public and non-public members:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;

var pt = Type.GetType("<Program>$");
var flags =
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;
foreach (var member in pt.GetMembers(flags))
{
    Console.WriteLine(member);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [.net-6.0](/questions/tagged/.net-6.0) the generational patterns were changed (as it was mentioned in the original feature spec, names for generated class and method are implementation depended), now the generated class name is `Program` which is now covered in [the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements#semantics):

> The type is named "Program", so can be referenced by name from source code. It is a partial type, so a type named "Program" in source code must also be declared as partial.

But the name for the synthesized `Main` method is (still) implementation depended:

> But the method name "Main" is used only for illustration purposes, the actual name used by the compiler is implementation dependent and the method cannot be referenced by name from source code.

There is another thing to note - this method is an entry point of the assembly:

> The method is designated as the entry point of the program. Explicitly declared methods that by convention could be considered as an entry point candidates are ignored.

So you can access it via [`Assembly.EntryPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.entrypoint?view=net-6.0) property (so no need to rely on the name):

```
var assemblyEntryPoint = typeof(Program).Assembly.EntryPoint;
```