# How do I get the Reflection TypeInfo of a C# 9 program that use Top-level statements?

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-9.0, toplevel-statement

Assume I have a simple script writing in C# 9 like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

// What to put in the ???
var exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(???).Assembly.Location);
```

Before, with the full program, we can use the `Main` class as an "indicator" class. `this` and `this.GetType()` is not available because technically it's inside a static method. How do I get it now?

---

A workaround I thought of while typing the question is `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()`:

```
var exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location);
```

It works for my case, but I can only get the `Assembly`, not the `TypeInfo` that in which the code is running.

Comment: May be try to do it via executing method: `MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType`

Comment: You may look at [Cannot find Main method using reflection with .NET 5 top level calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64966831/cannot-find-main-method-using-reflection-with-net-5-top-level-calls), seems to be a dupe candidate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest starting from the *method* which is executing (`Main`):

```
TypeInfo result = MethodBase
  .GetCurrentMethod() // Executing method         (e.g. Main)
  .DeclaringType      // Type where it's declared (e.g. Program)
  .GetTypeInfo();
```

If you want `Type`, not `TypeInfo` drop the last method:

```
Type result = MethodBase
  .GetCurrentMethod() // Executing method         (e.g. Main)
  .DeclaringType;     // Type where it's declared (e.g. Program)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also get the assembly using [`GetEntryAssembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly?view=net-5.0).

Once you have the assembly that your code is in, you can get its [`EntryPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.entrypoint?view=net-5.0), which is the compiler-generated "`Main`" method. You can then do `DeclaringType` to get the `Type`:

```
Console.WriteLine(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().EntryPoint.DeclaringType);
```

The above should get the compiler-generated "`Program`" class even if you are not at the top level.

Comment: Dang I feel super bad that I cannot mark both answers as correct. I would mark the other as it is "nearer" to my question, but your answer is still so good. Thank you, I learnt something new today.

Answer (score 5):

For C# 10 ([See 4th point in the breaking changes](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/compilers/CSharp/Compiler%20Breaking%20Changes%20-%20post%20DotNet%205.md)) compiler generates `Program` class for top-level statements so you can use it:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Program).FullName);
```

And though original (C# 9) [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements#semantics) state that:

> Note that the names "Program" and "Main" are used only for illustrations purposes, actual names used by compiler are implementation dependent and neither the type, nor the method can be referenced by name from source code.

[ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#aspnet-core-6-9) integration testing docs rely on this naming convention for the class.